# Jenkins: Configuring adb

Tags: android, jenkins, ant, automation, adb

My system is connected to the jenkins. I can run adb devices in my system and jenkins is able to execute all the tests in my machine.

But, in cases where `adb` is involved, jenkins displays `adb command not found`.

I can get `adb` in my machine which is connected to jenkins

I have defined both `ANDRIOD_HOME` and `ANT_HOME` in the environment variables **in the slave**(which is my own machine where adb is recognized)

ANDROID_HOME - sdk path
ANT_HOME = which ant [image]

Is there any thing else, that should be done?  I keep getting `adb command not found` when jenkins executes `adb devices`

Comment: what user is Jenkins running as on the slave? Guessing adb is not accessible for that user

Comment: Jenkins admin user! It shows like `started by ADMIN` and when i click on it, it displays, `Jenkins user`

Answer (score 0):

Setting `ANDROID_HOME` does not give the user access to `adb` via the `PATH`.  You'll need to either add a script to add `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to the `PATH` on startup for that user, or switch the scripts to use `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb` instead of just `adb`.